# How to work with circumflex accent in html textarea?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have textarea in HTML file and I need to work with circumflex accent, that means a user need to have an option to type characters like:

```
ŝĝĉ
```

If I try to type it now, it does nothing (it does not type anything). Where could be problem?

I already use:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The other not common characters works well, for example:

```
ěščř
```

Comment: Let me understand: is the `ŝĝĉ` good or bad?

Comment: @MoshFeu I updated my question.

Comment: If you try to do copy/paste (for those characters) Is it working?

Comment: @MoshFeu Surprisingly yes.

Comment: Maybe you have a pattern tester on your textarea (some plugin or framework or something) that does not allow to the user to type those character (by using regex `[A-Za-z]` for example)

Comment: Please show the code how you have set up the textarea. Have you checked your keyboard preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by js:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) 
{
    var keycode1 = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode1 == 0 || keycode1 == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

the solution was the change to:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) 
{
    var keycode1 = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode1 == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Now it works well. It is possible to type the characters and it still escape the "tab".